# leer varias lineas en python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Nesesito leer varias lineas en python 3,Tengo esto sin presionar ENTER:
Amor Roma
Hola Hello
ocasionalmente Escalonamiento
oso perro
Posesionarais posesionarias
Colombia Locombia
Mama Mami
y nesesito que python me lea todas las lineas y me imprima en una lista 
[[Amor,roma].[Hola,Hello]......]

¿Alguna manera de resolver esto?
Gracias!

Comment: Según entiendo, quieres que de una serie de palabras que **tú escribes en la consola**, al presionar Enter te cree una serie de listas, y que cada una contenga 2 palabras y que estas estén consecutivas/a la par. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: si eso, pues el programa deberia funcionar cuando se oprime enter, sin importar el numero de parejas de palabras....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
palabras = "primera segunda tercera cuarta"

lista_palabras = palabras.split(" ")
lista_pares_palabras = []
for i in range(0, len(lista_palabras),2):
    lista_pares_palabras.append([lista_palabras[i],lista_palabras[i+1]])


print(lista_pares_palabras)
```

**output:**

> [['primera', 'segunda'], ['tercera', 'cuarta']]